# New "millenium bug" with Mongo aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have been using for about six months this aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $isoWeek: "$createdAt" },
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      fonte: { $push: "$source" },
      appointments: { $push: "$appointment" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: { week: "$_id" }
  },
  {
    $project: { _id: 0 }
  },
  {
    $limit: 2
  }
]
```

Now it's retrieving random weeks since there are two years.

The solution seems easy but I cannot wrap my head around this, I have wasted way too much time already on this.

I have tried multiple grouping, matching to no avail.

The expected result is to get the last two weeks worth of data (production statistics) that is then further processed with normal js and displayed in a CRM.

**Edit**

Present Result:

```
[
  {
    count: 13,
    fonte: [
      'casalugano.ch', 'homegate.ch',
      'casalugano.ch', 'homegate.ch',
      'tutti.ch',      'homegate.ch',
      'homegate.ch',   'casalugano.ch',
      'tutti.ch',      'homegate.ch',
      'homegate.ch',   'homegate.ch',
      'homegate.ch'
    ],
    appointments: [],
    week: 1
  },
  {
    count: 5,
    fonte: [
      'casalugano.ch',
      'homegate.ch',
      'tutti.ch',
      'homegate.ch',
      'homegate.ch'
    ],
    appointments: [],
    week: 52
  }
]
```

Expected result would be to get the *present* week and the *last* week's worth of data (week 2 and 1).

Comment: It would be nice if you can share sample documents in json format.

Comment: Do you mean of the outcome I am getting now?

Comment: The sample input documents, your current result, and the expected result would be best. Also if you use mongoose, the schema code would be fine.

Comment: That's way too much data to post in a single question, the Schema itself is immense.. I'll add something..

Comment: Even week 1 is completely off, there must be a weird system for detecting new year in mongo, maybe next week it'll normalize as this week (2) is being properly counted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've handled it this way:

```
{
                $group: {
                    _id: { $isoWeek: '$createdAt' },
                    count: { $sum: 1 },
                    fonte: { $push: '$fonte' },
                    appointments: { $push: '$appointment' }
                }
            },
            {
                $addFields: { week: '$_id' }
            },
            {
                $project: { _id: 0 }
            },
            /*{
                $limit: 2
            }*/
            {
                $match: { week: { $gte: getWeekNumber(new Date()) - 1, $lte: getWeekNumber(new Date()) } }
            }
```

`getWeekNumber` is just an helper function that returns ISO week and then I manually reverse the array.

If anyone has a cleaner answer, it's welcome!